# Word Interop - How to Place an Image at Very Top of Document Using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have tried removing headers and footers and setting margins to zero, but my image is never at the very top of the page.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

//Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
winword.Visible = false;

//Create a missing variable for missing value
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

//Create a new document
Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
// Get the Logo file name
var eFaxLogo = String.Format(@"{0}\PSILogo.jpg", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logo"]);

foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
{
    Range headerRange = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    headerRange.Delete();
    Range footerRange = section.Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    footerRange.Delete();
}

//adding text to document
document.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0F;
document.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0F;
document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
document.Content.Font.Size = 54;
document.Content.Font.Name = "Arial Black";
document.Content.Text = "Fax " + Environment.NewLine;

...

// Add a picture
object docRange = document.Range();
string imagePath = "C:\\Temp\\6clubs.png";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape pic = document.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, ref missing, ref missing, ref docRange);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape = pic.ConvertToShape();
shape.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
```

I have noticed that if I drop the picture in last that the wdWrapBehind works just fine.  However, if I insert the picture first, not so much.

It is a requirement that the picture be placed at the very top (i.e. zero margin) of the page.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Actually, this should be possible with using a Frame. If you're still looking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Word `Frame` to contain the image, orient the frame using `RelativeVerticalPosition`, and place the image at the top of the page with `VerticalPosition`.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

//Create a missing variable for missing value
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Word.Document ActiveDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
Word.Range headerRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
ActiveDoc.Frames.Add(headerRange);
//Place Frame at top of page
headerRange.Frames[1].RelativeVerticalPosition = Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;
headerRange.Frames[1].VerticalPosition = 0;
headerRange.Frames[1].Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
//Add image
object docRange = headerRange.Frames[1].Range;
string imagePath = @"C:\Temp\6clubs.png";
ActiveDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, ref missing, ref missing, ref docRange);
```

Comment: That did it!  I made a few changes that allow me to keep the document margins and position the image at the top left of the page.  I'll post the finished code below.  Thank you very much!